# How to disable evil insert key in read only mode

Tags: evil, read-only-mode

I want to disable evil insert key such as `a`, `i`, `o` in `read-only` mode (keep navigation key such as `j` and `k`), my idea is to disable these keys in local buffer when enabling `read-only` mode and enable these keys after disabling `read-only` mode.

There are two difficulties for me:

1. How to disable evil insert key.
2. How to execute code when enable/disable mode.

I notice there is `evil-disable-insert-state-bindings` variable. I try to set it to `t` in local buffer, but `a`, `i` keys still work.

I know I can use `(add-hook 'read-only-mode-hook (lambda () (message "read-only-mode changed")))` to detect mode change, but I don't know how to distinguish enabling and disabling mode.

Answer (score 0):

For read-only buffers, Evil provides the Evil specific `motion-state` (see [here](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#modes-and-states)). You can configure the modes to open in that state by adding/removing the mode names to the list of `evil-motion-state-modes`.

If you are using Spacemacs then you can also use the [evilified-state](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/CONVENTIONS.html#evilified-buffers) in a similar way (or when not using Spacemacs you could try https://github.com/mohsenil85/evil-evilified-state, I guess it works fine, but I have never tested it).

Alternatively, I think I would recommend to just use the very well designed [evil-collection](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection), although as a Spacemacs user I haven't used it much myself.